# Reverse for 'user_review_list' not found. 'user_review_list' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

**Even after going through similar STACKOVERFLOW solutions this doubt was not solved.**
I have also been through other resources.
Been engaged in django since 2 days only !! :)

project -> winerama

app ->reviews

my views.py

```
 def review_list(request):
    latest_review_list  =Review.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:9]
    context ={'latest_review_list': latest_review_list}
    return render(request, 'reviews/review_list.html',context)

 def wine_list(request):
    wine_list  =Wine.objects.order_by('-name')
    context ={'wine_list':wine_list}
    return render(request, 'reviews/wine_list.html',context)

 def review_detail(request , review_id):
    review = get_object_or_404(Review , pk = review_id)
    context = {'review':review}
    return render(request,'reviews/review_detail.html',context)


 def wine_detail(request , review_id):
    wine = get_object_or_404(Wine, pk = wine_id)
    context = {'wine':wine}
    return render(request,'reviews/wine_detail.html',context)

 def add_review(request,wine_id):
    wine = get_object_or_404(Wine , pk = wine_id)
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
        comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
        user_name=form.cleaned_data['user_name']
        review  =Review()
        review.wine = wine
        review.user_name = user_name
        review.user_name = user_name
        review.rating  =rating
        review.comment = comment
        review.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        review.save()
        return HttpRespponseRedirect(reverse('reviews:wine_detail',args = (wine.id,)))
    return render(request,'reviews/wine_detail.html',{'wine':wine,'form':form})`
```

**reviews/urls.py**

```
 urlpatterns = [
     # ex: /
     url(r'^$', views.review_list, name='review_list'),
     # ex: /review/5/
     url(r'^review/(?P<review_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.review_detail, name='review_detail'),
     # ex: /wine/
     url(r'^wine$', views.wine_list, name='wine_list'),
     # ex: /wine/5/
     url(r'^wine/(?P<wine_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.wine_detail, name='wine_detail'),
     url(r'^wine/(?P<wine_id>[0-9]+)/add_review/$', views.add_review, name='add_review'),
 ]
```

**reviews/templates/reviews/base.html**

```
 {% block bootstrap3_content %}
 <div class="container">
     <nav  class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="navbar-header">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'review_list' %}">Winerama</a>
         </div>
         <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li><a href="{% url 'wine_list' %}">Wine list</a></li>
                 <li><a href="{% url 'review_list' %}">Home</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </nav>

     <h1>{% block title %}(no title){% endblock %}</h1>

     {% bootstrap_messages %}

     {% block content %}(no content){% endblock %}
 </div>

 {% endblock %}
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE.
PLEASE HELP ME FOR THE SAME.

Comment: post the error log message screenshot.

Comment: Can you check that if you included a url tag like this **{% url 'user_review_list' %}** in any of your templates?

Comment: @AjmalNoushad, Thatswhy I asked for error log to see, where he has included that.

Comment: ERROR SOLVED.. :)

Comment: @Shaun_stark007, what was that?

Comment: I just started coding the entire project again....I could not find the mistake but I finally got the correct output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is **self explanatory**:

Somewhere in your `template html` you have written

```
{% url 'user_review_list' %}
```

That means you are calling `user_review_list` function, but it is **not defined in views**. Instead you have defined `review_list` function.

Comment: Sir this is the only and complete  template file I have made and  have not mentioned 'user_review_list' anywhere in my entire project :(

Comment: I had this issue when i added namespace for `urlpatterns`. please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378019/django-rest-framework-noreversematch-error-even-when-pattern-name-has-been-defi